# Should I include numbers on my NMDS axes?

Tags: data-visualization, multidimensional-scaling

The actual values of NMDS axes are essentially arbitrary, as I understand them - there's no meaning to be gained from a value of 1 or 100 or 10,000. In keeping with good design principles should I drop the axis text and background grid and just include the zero-lines for each axis? Or is there something I'm missing that can be gleaned from keeping the actual values? The plot with no values (other than 0) actually looks a little *too* empty to me.

With axis text and background grid:

[image]

Without:

[image]